# Classifying Binary Associativity as a Unary Property

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, category-theory

I'm working on a combinatorial style problem, specifically enumerating binary functions $\mu(x,y):  M \times M \rightarrow M, x \in M, y \in M$ that are associative (here $M$ can be thought of as some set, though in my exact context it happens to be a group)

Is there some way I can restate the property "$\mu(x,y)$ is a binary associative function from $M \times M \rightarrow M$ where $x \in M$, $y \in M$ " as "$\mu(s)$ is a $W$ unary function from $M \times M \rightarrow M$ $s \in M \times M$" where $W$ is an adjective that characterizes the unary functions which if examined from the binary viewpoint, would be associative.

I feel it will be easier then to just consider all functions from $M \times M \rightarrow M$ (thats easy to enumerate) and instead only opt to look at functions that satisfy the property $W$. But it's not clear what that property is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the following, but comment if I'm mistaken.

First, we need the functorial action of $\times$ on functions which is $(f\times g)(x,y) = (f(x),g(y))$.  From there, associativity of a function $m : M\times M \to M$ is the following equation:
$$m \circ (m\times id) = m \circ (id \times m) \circ \alpha_{M,M,M}$$
where $\alpha_{X,Y,Z} : (X \times Y) \times Z \to X \times (Y \times Z)$ via
$\alpha_{X,Y,Z}((x,y),z) = (x,(y,z))$ natural in $X$, $Y$, and $Z$.

In diagramatic form,

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(M\times M)\times M @>\alpha>> M\times(M\times M) @>id\times m>> M\times M \\
@VVm\times idV @. @VVmV \\
M\times M @= M\times M @>>m> M
\end{CD}$$

Comment: I lose you at the line containing $m \circ (m \times id) = m \circ ( id \times m) \circ \alpha_{M,M,M}$ I believe I know what this is stating $m(x,m(y,z)) = m(m(x,y),z)$ but its not clear to me how to discern that meaning from what you have written.

Comment: Or before I bog you with questions, does this make it easier to characterize and compute associative functions from some set $M$? I posed the question, but I don't know if what I am asking is the wisest way to go about enumerating such associative-functions. If yes, then I'll proceed to distill exactly what you have written (of course with your help by a couple questions in the comments :) )

Comment: $\circ$ is just normal composition of functions, and two functions are equal when they give equal results for equal arguments.  Simplifying the left-hand side, $(m\circ(m\times id))((x,y),z) = m((m\times id)((x,y),z)) = m(m(x,y),z)$.

Comment: As for the enumerating, it's not obvious to me that this will help. Personally, though I'm not saying this is better, I'd probably start with the fact that a closed associative binary operation is a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) homomorphism into the endofunction monoid. There's a bijection between semigroup homomorphisms $A\to B$ and subsemigroups of $A\times B$ for which $\pi_1 : A\times B\to A$ restricts to a bijection. Thus the problem is counting those special subsemigroups. [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A023814) suggests this isn't completely unreasonable.

Comment: Actually, I take back the "isn't completely unreasonable" part of my previous comment. While the statements are true, your original question is equivalent to "how many semigroups are there on $A$?" My "reduction" probably didn't make that problem easier. *Maybe* considering semigroup homomorphisms into endofunctions might be valuable, but more likely it won't make a difference.

Comment: Interesting... It seems this is going to be a hard computation no matter what hat trick I try to pull